# In a docker file LABEL command is it possible to "quote" an ARG?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a docker file I pass in a "build arg" which is a string with whitespace in it.

I want to use it to set a label as in:

```
ARG MyString
LABEL my.key="${MyString}"
```

However the `${MyString}` or if it is `$MyString` is not expanded.  Is it possible to do this or do I need to pass in the quotes in the ARG

Answer (score 0):

Well it seem it does expand it just is not echoed expanded when the command is echoed by `docker build`.  So one must actually test the results to see if it worked :)